# phpmyadmin error in tcpdf_autoconfig.php#96 when i want to import or export

Tags: php, mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export

When I click on export, I get this error.
[image: When I click on export, I get this error.]

When I click on import, I get this error
[image: When I click on import, I get this error.]

I use PHP 8.0.3 and phpmyadmin 5.1.0 and 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2 - Debian 9.13

Comment: this os a apache or nginx problem for apache do add the path tpo https://stackoverflow.com/a/52774342/5193536 something simiar is possible for nginx if you use that

Answer (score 0):

This openbase dir error was fixed in 5.1.1, you will need to upgrade

See: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16709